# What is the flow of execution once you access a static variable of a class?

Tags: c#, static, static-classes

I have a structure on the lines of

```
public static class BuildVersion
{
    public static Version v1// a Version variable
    {
        get
        {
            isVersionV1Updated=true;
            return getVersion("v1");//this is a helper method to get versions
        }
    }
    public static Version v2
    {
        get {
            isVersionV1Updated=false;
            return getVersion("v2");
        }
    }
    public static bool isVersionV1Updated = false;
    public static Version getVersion(string versionString)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(versionString+" updated");
        //do something
        return requiredVersion;
    }
}
```

Now, what will happen when I set BuildVersion.isVersionUpdated=true?

1. I mean, what would be the flow, will variables v1 and v2 get
   populated?
2. If yes, will the output print "v1 updated" and "v2
   updated" appear as output?
3. Will it make a difference if I make the class 'BuildVersion'as non-static

P.S. Pardon if the question is too naive, I am curios about the flow of where the control flows when you do "BuildVersion.someVariable"

Comment: Maybe but a breakpoint in and run it and find out?  That has got to be less trouble than posting a question here!

Comment: `BuildVersion.isVersionUpdated = true` would just set the value of that field to `true`.

Comment: You ask us what will happen, why don't you try it out yourself? Do you want to test us?

Comment: I tried with a non static class, but I am getting some strange behaviour; it prints "v1 updated" and "v2 updated" on console, and I am not sure that's supposed to happen. That's why the question

Comment: `v1` and `v2` are properties, not variables. The only way you're going to see the code in there execute is if you're actually reading those properties somewhere. Setting `isVersionV1Updated=true` only sets that field, it does not in any way execute the code in those two properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first, with non-static class you get data in the output window, coz probably when you create the class instance, after that you had fetched v1 & v2.
To answer your question:
1. No.When you set isVersionUpdated=true, v1 & v2 still remains untouched.
2. Not at this moment, but if in your code ,when you will try to get v1 or v2, it will.
3. Normal classes can have static & non static methods/props so,suit yourself(if you feel later on you might need non static prop & methods).

Comment: The property getters are only invoked when the properties are read, not when the class in initialised, whether they're static or not.  Static _fields_ would be initialised when the class is initialised, but these are properties.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Oh yes.My bad !! I have updated the answer.Thanks

Comment: So as I understand, it is:
For non-static class, 
BuildVersion.IsVersionV1Updated=true

 would populate values v1 and v2 and as I would be creating an instance(which does load all properties).

Comment: @RonakAgrawal I have updated the answer recentlt.just check.

Comment: @RonakAgrawal no.that's incorrect.IsVersionV1Updated will never populate v1 & v2, all three are entirely independent.

Comment: So, why do i get "v1 updated" and "v2 updated" in the console output, when I try to set BuildVersion.isVersionV1Updated=true, for a non static class?

Comment: @RonakAgrawal are you sure you haven't accessed v1 & v2? add your client function where you have used non-static class

Comment: Yeah. I l just try again and check once if I am missing something trivial.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93053/discussion-between-ronak-agrawal-and-techiebee).

Comment: @RonakAgrawal I have checked it in my sample & it works correctly. No output with non static method unless accessed v1 & v2.